# Key binding of custom snippet in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-extensions

VS code: *1.28.1*

Mac OS High Sierra *10.13.6*

I have created a custom snippet to add interpolation in HTML file. it works fine when using *F1 >insert snippet* way But I need to add keybinding so that it works with keyboards. here what I have done but it does not work.

create a snippet with help of [vs code tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

```
{
  "interpolate": {
    "prefix": "inter",
    "body": ["{{ ${CLIPBOARD} |json }}"],
    "description": "Interpolate this"
  }
}
```

Now I need to bind with the key shortcut and add this in keybindings.json

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+i",
    "command": "editor.action.interpolate",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "langId": "html",
      "name": "interpolate"
    }
  }
```

But whenever I hit <kbd>Cmd+Shift+I</kbd>. throw error

> "command 'editor.action.interpolate' not found

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find the solution, we need to add the value of *name* in *keybindings.json* same as the key of user snippet file *html.json*

#### html.json

```
{
  "interpolate": { // this is the name of snippet
    "prefix": "inter",
    "body": ["{{ ${CLIPBOARD} |json }}"],
    "description": "Interpolate this"
  }
}
```

#### keybindings.json

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+I",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "langId": "html",
      "name": "interpolate" << same as name of snippet
    }
  }
```

Comment: You already had the correct "name".  What you needed to change was the command to "editor.action.isertSnippet".  Your snippet does not create a command like you had.

Comment: This also needs package.json changes.
  "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "html",
        "path": "./snippetFile.json"
      }
    ]